Vue 4: Access window object in vue component
I want to get the text selected in a VueComponent and for this purpose, I want to use the
window.getSelection 

function. To have access to the window object, I tried
//in app.js

app.config.globalProperties.$stupidProp = { age: 30, name: "Florian" };
app.config.globalProperties.$window = window;

and then in a function of
//mycomponent.vue
console.log( this.$stupidProp ); //gives undefined
console.log( this.$window ); //gives undefined

What do I do wrong? The app.config.globalProperties.$window stuff comes from here: How to access the window object in vue js?
It works for Vue3, which I probably have.
At the end of my body element, I have the following imports
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue3-sfc-loader"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script> 


in previous versions you would bind window properties to a computed property. has that changed in vue4? is vue4 a thing? do you mean 3.4?

"have the lastest version of Vue" - and you know this because?.. If you're in control of your app, you're capable to know which version you use. There's no Vue 4. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown where you use this.$window.getSelection(), it's safe to assume you use it incorrectly, and you're asking about a wrong thing. Also $window serves no good purpose in general

@danielRICADO I probably mean Vue 3.4. How to do that exactly, binding window properties (such as the selection) to a computed property?

This makes no sense. The window variable is inherently a global JavaScript variable. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Here you can read more about Vue 3's global variable management: Add global variable in Vue 3 - SO; app.config.globalProperties - Vue Docs

https://medium.com/@jamesweee/reactive-window-parameters-in-vuejs-fc5de75d7ab5 here isa blog that shows you how. The linked thread whe this was marked duplicate extend the bvue prototype which seems unnecessary when you can just access as a computed prop.

I somehow managed to solve my problem. The code inside my vue component function looks like this now:
//vuecomponent.js
        console.log("A method in my vue component is executed!");
        console.log(this.$stupidProp); //gives undefined
        console.log(this.$window); //undefined
        console.log(this.window); //gives the correct window object

       console.log(this.$router.$stupidProp ); //gives the correct 
                   stupidProp object
       console.log(this.$router.stupidProp ); //undefined
       console.log(this.$router.$window2); //undefined
       console.log(this.$router.window2); //gives correct window object

The corresponding code in app.js looks like this:
const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  // 4. Provide the history implementation to use. We are using the hash history for simplicity here.
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes, // short for `routes: routes`
});

router.$window = window;
router.$stupidProp = { age: 30, name: "Florian" };

router.window2 = window;
router.stupidProp2 = { age: 30, name: "Florian" };

/*
Vue.prototype.$window = window;
Vue.prototype.$stupidprop = { stupid: "This is a stupid object", age: 12 }; */
app.config.globalProperties.stupidProp = { age : 30, name: "Florian" };
console.log(app.config.globalProperties.stupidProp);

app.config.globalProperties.window = window;
console.log(app.config.globalProperties.window);

console.log(window);



app.use(router);
app.mount("#gaps");

So I have also set the window object as a property of my router ( a hack of course ). Having written this, I don't really understand what the dollar sign does nor which line of code in app.js (where I set the property) and which line of code in vuecomponent.js (where I access the property) go together. But it works at least now!

You don't need to do anything of this. This is a workaround for a problem that doesn't exist.  You can access window as is through the app. The only real reasons for globalProperties.window is to access it in templates, which is a bad practice any way. And to improve  testability, but this is rarely required and is done on demand.
